# Run same python module simultaneously multiple times in same python script in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, asynchronous

So I need a way to run multiple times simultaneously,asynchronous of same module in same time. I know it's something with asynco in python 3 but how to do that in python 2? Any idea?

here is example of code:

**MainPython.py**

```
from SecondPython import Single
mydata = {"1": {"stat": ""}, "2": {"stat": "1"}, "3": {"stat": ""}}
cnt = 0
for i in range(len(mydata.keys())):
    result = Single(mydata, "browser")
    if result == 101:
        print "do this"
        cnt += 1
        if cnt >= 5:
           break
    else:
        print "do thata"
```

**SecondPython.py**

```
class Single:
    def __init__(self,worker_data,myobject):
        print "gather provided intel"
        print worker_data
        self.data1 = worker_data['stats']
        if self.data1 == "1":
             return 101
        self.myobject = myobject # myobject is an object
```